# Spring Roo , jQuery, jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, spring-roo

I am attempting to use jQuery Mobile in Spring Roo.

When I login to my application the application displays the source code for the last included javascript file.

Take a look at mjquery-scripts.tagx file below.

Notice that whatever is the last included file, the source code of that file, will be displayed in the browser.

The address will be something like https://testdomain.com:8080/scripts/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js

Now, when I type the url https://testdomain.com:8080/ I will be shown the proper page.

The problem seems to be that on login the redirection is to the path scripts/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js .

What could be causing this problem?

Even though I have indicated jquery.mobile this problem happens for jquery.min too.

The default load-scripts.tagx works just fine.

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">

<spring:url value="/scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" var="jQuery_URL" />
<spring:url value="/scripts/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" var="mobile_CSS" />
<spring:url value="/scripts/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" var="mobile_js" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${mobile_CSS}"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jQuery_URL}"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${mobile_js}"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a silly problem on my part.

I placed the jquery js files in the /src/main/webapp/scripts folder.

Moved them over to

/src/main/resources/web-resources

as in the following:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">

<spring:url value="/resources/jquery-1.7-min/jquery-1.7.min.js" var="jQuery_URL" />
<spring:url value="/resources/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" var="mobile_CSS" />
<spring:url value="/resources/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" var="mobile_js" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${mobile_CSS}"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${jQuery_URL}"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${mobile_js}"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>

</jsp:root>
```

Now it works as expected.